# Unable to append form key values to ``formData`` in my react hooks component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, form-data

Unable to append form key values to `formData` in my react hooks component, it is always coming as undefined. Can someone please advise the problem here ?

```
 "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   "react-hook-form": "^7.4.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

//component :

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [formRegister, setRegister] = useState({
    _id: "",
    nomineename: "",
    nomineeemail: "",
    description: "",
    nominatedby: ""
  });
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRegister({ ...formRegister, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    // for(let key in formRegister) {
    //     formData.append(key, formRegister[key]);
    // }
    Object.entries(formRegister).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };
    const fetchData = async (formData) => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.post(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/nominateperson",
          formData,
          config
        );
        if (res.data) {
          console.log("Link token created:" + res.data);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Nominate Person</h1>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="linkForm inputForm"
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <div className="inputField">
          <input
            name="nomineename"
            placeholder="nominate a person"
            type="text"
            {...register("nomineename", {
              required: "Nominate a person is required !",
              pattern: {
                value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]/,
                message: "Invalid name !"
              }
            })}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <span className="nominateError">
          <pre>{errors.nomineename && errors.nomineename.message}</pre>
        </span>
        <div className="inputField">
          <input
            name="email"
            placeholder="nominee email"
            type="text"
            {...register("email", {
              required: "Nominee email is required !",
              pattern: {
                value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                message: "Invalid email address !"
              }
            })}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <span className="nominateError">
          <pre>{errors.email && errors.email.message}</pre>
        </span>
        <div className="inputField">
          <textarea
            name="description"
            placeholder="reason for nomination"
            maxLength={1000}
            {...register("description", {
              required: "Description is required !"
            })}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <span className="nominateError">
          <pre>{errors.description && errors.description.message}</pre>
        </span>
        <div className="inputField nominatedby">
          <input
            name="nominatedby"
            placeholder="nominated by"
            type="text"
            {...register("nominatedby", {
              required: "Nominated by is required !",
              pattern: {
                value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{2,30}$/,
                message: "Invalid name !"
              }
            })}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <span className="nominateError">
          <pre>{errors.nominatedby && errors.nominatedby.message}</pre>
        </span>
        <span className="getlinkbutton">
          <input type="submit" />
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-flower-56sle?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: But it's working?? Try adding `console.log(formData.get("email"), formData.get("nomineename"));` right after the `Object.entries` call. You just have a param naming clash in `const fetchData = async (formData)` line. Remove that param or pass formData in the `fetchData(formData)` call. You're welcome =)

Comment: Sorry I can't see the formData ..

Comment: @Tyblitz I have added the screenshot for reference. Set a breakpoint and while hovering the formData nothing got displayed. While iterating in the forEach() the i could see keys and values

Comment: that's normal, you can't see the keys/values assigned to formData, you need to call FormData.get('key'). I'm 200% sure it works

Comment: In the server side I am getting error 500, error details as follows: ``fail: 'notNull Violation: nominations.email cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: nominations.nomineename cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: nominations.description cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: nominations.nominatedby cannot be null'``

Comment: ``app.post('/service/nominateperson', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const nomineeName = req.body.nomineename;
    const nomineeEmail = req.body.nomineeemail;
// ....similarly other fields ...                                                                                              var data = {nomineename:nomineeName, email:nomineeEmail, description:description, nominatedby:nominatedBy};
const nominationData = await NominationModel.create(data);``

Comment: You can validate which all fields you must always send and have them default as null in case user doesn't feed them. The problem you are mentioning is more of a backend issue. Your original query seems to be resolved now.

Comment: @soccerway why do you bother using FormData if you have a NodeJS back-end and no multi-part body (e.g. mp3 file)? You could simply send content-type `application/json` and send `formRegistration` directly with axios in that case. For FormData in express you need an extra dependency like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and it's overkill for simple text data

Comment: Yes, got your point, that make sense. I will remove formData from usage. Since I had multiple fields I thought it might be good option to use FormData. But this approach is bit hassle to handle at server side which I don’t need to do! Thanks for pointing out.